# Radius of convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

> Given the sequence:
>
> $$a_n = \frac{2n+1}{2n-3}a_{n-1} -\frac{1}{2n-3}$$
>
> Find its radius of convergence.
>
> **HINT:** Show that the coefficients have a lower limit and that they do not grow faster than $5^n$

**What I have tried:**

First I looked for a pattern; we know that $a_{n-1}$ is:

$$a_{n-1} = \frac{2(n-1)+1}{2(n-1)-3}a_{n-2} -\frac{1}{2(n-1)-3} = \frac{2n-1}{2n-5}a_{n-2} -\frac{1}{2n-5}$$

So we get:

$$a_n = \frac{\Pi_{j=1}^{n}(2j+1)}{\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(2i-3)}a_{0} -\frac{1}{\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(2i-3)} = (2n+1)(2n-1)a_0 -\frac{1}{\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(2i-3)} $$

I was trying to apply the ratio test but things get messy.

I was thinking about the hint; I know I'll have to argue about lim sup $\lvert a_{n+1} \frac{1}{a_{n}}\rvert  \le 5$ but I do not get to this point.

Answer: The radius of convergence is 1.

Comment: apply the absolute ratio test $\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \bigg | < 1$

Comment: @Clark that's what I tried but as I said things get over-complicated. That's why I thought I had to have a mistake in my calculations.

Comment: you show what $a_n$ is above, $a_{n+1}$ isn't too complicated. If you don't want to do the division use mathematica/wolfram to do the simplification, and see what you get

Comment: Yeah it is straightforward:$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \bigg |  = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{2n+3}{2n-1}}{\frac{2n+1}{2n-3}} =1$ (I've dropped the second term, which goes to zero)

Comment: if the absolute ratio tests returns exactly 1, the absolute convergence of the series is inconclusive, hence the strict inequality '<' This is probably why you stated there is a hint

Comment: @Clark I've got 1 yes. So $\bigg | x \bigg | \le 1$ is my result. Note I have not used the hint. I am curious in how could I use it though. Do you know it? I guess there's another approach to the problem based on lim sup $\lvert a_{n+1} \frac{1}{a_{n}}\rvert  \le 5$ but how?